# How to fix LazyInitializationException in hibernate JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

There is a **@ManyToMany** table:
**User**, **user_role**, **roleuser**.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dwZn.png)

The **roleuser** table contains roles: **ROLE_USER**, **ROLE_ADMIN** and others.

This is how I make the **@ManyToMany** tables relate to each other:

**User.class**

```
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    public List<Role> getRoleList() {
        return roleList;
    }
```

**Role.class**

```
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roleList", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<User> getUserList() {
        return userList;
    }    



    public void addPerson(User user) {
        userList.add( user );
        user.getRoleList().add( this );
    }
```

And this is how I add the user:

**AddUser.class**

```
    User user = new User("Michael Joseph Jackson");

    Role role = serviceJpa.findRoleByRole("ROLE_USER");
    role.addPerson(user);

    serviceJpa.saveRole(role);
```

The bottom line is that I don't want to use **fetch = FetchType.EAGER**. One role can have thousands of users, and I don't want to get all thousand users when I access the role. But to do this, I have to change **FetchType.EAGER** to **FetchType.LAZY**, but then in this case, a well-known error occurs when I add a user:

> **Message** Request processing failed; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize
> a collection of role: com.test.shop.model.user.Role.userList,
> could not initialize proxy - no Session

I don’t know what to do about it.
Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to also assign to the user a list of roles.  Try doing this.

Comment: How should I assign a list of roles? I have a role and I am assigning this role to a new user. How else should I assign a list of roles to a user? Can you show?

Comment: why should you have relation from role to user ? and why should role have those cascades on user ? but you might be able to solve your problem with adding @Transactional on the methods that you are using User or Role.

Comment: @AliDahaghin You speak: why should you have relation from role to user ? Otherwise, my user is not added.

Answer (score 0):

I thinking your code is a bad pattern, when you call
`serviceJpa.saveRole(role);`
jpa first loading roll.userList and adding user into it, then saving it's relation.
therefore , **jpa first load roll.userList**, but you set roll.userList load as lazy so jpa can not load userList beacuse your session closed!!!
please read this [tutorial](https://thorben-janssen.com/lazyinitializationexception/)